# Generate N , 3 digit unique Random Integers where all digits are unique

Tags: java, java-8

Below is my code that i have tried so far and it works:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    Integer[] integers = random.ints(10, 100, 999).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
      String[] split = integers[i].toString().split("");
      int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
      a = Integer.valueOf(split[0]);
      b = Integer.valueOf(split[1]);
      c = Integer.valueOf(split[2]);
      if ((a != b) && (a != c) && (b != c)) {
        list.add(Integer.valueOf(integers[i]));
      }
    }
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

The output is correct.

> If **abc** is the integer then `a !=b` and `a ! c` and `b !=c` ,
>   making all digits unique.

I tried to apply the later part in stream but i am not getting the expected result. Could someone guide me where i am going wrong?

**Java-8 version:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random random = new Random();
    Integer[] integers = random.ints(10, 100, 999).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    String[] collect = Arrays.stream(integers).map(s -> {
      String[] split = s.toString().split("");
      return split;
    }).filter(
        k -> (Integer.valueOf(k[0]) != Integer.valueOf(k[1])) && (Integer.valueOf(k[0]) != Integer
            .valueOf(k[2])) && (Integer.valueOf(k[1]) != Integer.valueOf(k[2])))
        .toArray(String [] ::new);
    Arrays.stream(collect).forEach(System.out::println);



  }
```

Comment: What results are you getting? How do they differ from the expect results?

Comment: *"and it works"* No it doesn't. It is supposed to generate 10 numbers. I ran it three times, and got 9, 5, and 7 results in those three attempts.

Comment: *"Java-8 version:"* The first block of code is Java 8+ too. And if you're thinking of modifying that label to say "Java 8 stream version", then look at first block of code again, because it uses a stream too.

Comment: You left a comment in a now-deleted question: *"for 100 sample random integers, you solution has repetitive numbers. [...] **532** is repeating two times"* --- Nothing in the question says you can't have duplicate numbers, only that you can't have duplicate digits *within* a number. You own code certainly makes no attempt whatsoever at preventing duplicate numbers, only duplicate digits. --- Please, never attempt to change the question in a comment to an answer, especially not as radical a change as that!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting a number to a string and calling `split("")` is about to **slowest** possible solution you could ever think up.

If you have a 3-digit number, and you want the 3 digits, use division and remainder operators:

```
int i = /*assign some non-negative number of at most 3 digits*/;
int d1 = i / 100;
int d2 = i / 10 % 10;
int d3 = i % 10;
```

---

If you need `N` numbers, you can't generate `N` numbers and then *discard* some of them. That would leave you with *fewer* than `N` numbers. You have to count *after* discarding bad numbers.

```
static int[] generate(int n) {
    // Numbers 100 and 101 contain duplicates, so lower limit is 102.
    // Upper limit is 987 (inclusive), since 988, 989, and 99x all contain duplicates.
    return new Random().ints(102, 988)
            .filter(Test::isThreeUniqueDigits)
            .limit(n)
            .toArray();
}
private static boolean isThreeUniqueDigits(int i) {
    int d1 = i / 100;
    int d2 = i / 10 % 10;
    int d3 = i % 10;
    return (d1 != d2 && d1 != d3 && d2 != d3);
}
```

Or use a lambda expression instead of a method reference:

```
static int[] generate(int n) {
    return new Random().ints(102, 988).filter(i -> {
                int d1 = i / 100, d2 = i / 10 % 10, d3 = i % 10;
                return (d1 != d2 && d1 != d3 && d2 != d3);
            }).limit(n).toArray();
}
```

*Sample results*

```
[416, 613, 401, 250, 507, 306, 179, 152, 850, 504]
[913, 304, 174, 874, 714, 245, 632, 890, 357, 382]
[618, 706, 946, 364, 209, 320, 690, 529, 824, 651]
[419, 386, 547, 471, 952, 917, 389, 469, 640, 285]
[120, 347, 549, 247, 619, 328, 814, 240, 984, 630]
[127, 174, 723, 287, 149, 329, 176, 964, 451, 617]
[539, 587, 768, 594, 296, 948, 157, 409, 952, 395]
[602, 392, 698, 761, 231, 764, 517, 147, 402, 841]
[194, 294, 923, 542, 362, 248, 352, 286, 407, 348]
[631, 502, 461, 439, 174, 278, 407, 394, 617, 370]
[754, 193, 539, 290, 504, 684, 921, 962, 724, 196]
[125, 586, 925, 857, 879, 761, 134, 620, 134, 723]
[457, 307, 524, 536, 249, 349, 901, 623, 247, 320]
[103, 903, 506, 645, 431, 802, 695, 761, 609, 867]
[569, 894, 608, 963, 681, 365, 162, 874, 452, 307]
[807, 178, 983, 837, 956, 273, 295, 527, 798, 406]
[157, 936, 398, 379, 618, 920, 957, 921, 430, 879]
[396, 280, 315, 569, 328, 138, 931, 623, 413, 926]
[987, 972, 518, 391, 138, 691, 372, 193, 402, 678]
[346, 328, 940, 768, 307, 419, 146, 950, 671, 530]
```

Comment: Classic answer! I also think `.split` is the slowest.

Comment: To be fair, one of the most expensive aspects of `.toString().split("")` is the conversion to a decimal representation bearing division and modulo by ten (an expensive often overlooked) whereas the creation of new strings and an array (an expensive often overestimated) is not that horrible, as all of them are tiny. So this approach keeps the expensive digit extraction and the repetition of the random number generation when the test failed. You can [generate valid numbers in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59786977/2711488) using only multiplication and addition.

Answer (score 3):

You are splitting the string and then not combining the split array after that.

Add `.map(strings -> String.join("", strings))` before `.toArray(String [] ::new);` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

One aspect is not dealt with: repeated numbers in the result.

One could collect the result in a set to have unique numbers too.
I used a LinkedHashSet which keeps the generated numbers in order of adding them,
not specifically sorted as would a HashSet (w.r.t. to the hashCode) or TreeSet (in order).

Then a list of random ints cannot be used because of duplicates needing more tries.

Your algorithm would become:

```
    // Maximal different numbers 9*9*8 as different digits 10*9*8 and first digit not 0.
    final int MAX_N = 9*9*8; // 648
    int size = N;
    if (size > MAX_N) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("More than maximum " + MAX_N + ": " + size);
    }
    Set<Integer> result = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int n = randomUnique(random);
        if (!result.add(n)) {
            --i; // Already added, take a new random int.
            // When size nears MAX_N the looping take enormous long!
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

But the random unique number picked can be made immediately right:

```
static int randomUnique(Random random) {
    // 1-9
    int d2 = 1 + random.nextInt(9);
    int n = d2;

    // 0-9 without d1
    int d1 = random.nextInt(9); // As index in those digits.
    if (d1 >= d2) {
        ++d1;
    }
    n = 10 * n + d1;

    // 0-9 without d1 and d2
    int d0 = random.nextInt(8); // As index in those digits.
    if (d0 >= d1 || d0 >= d2) {
        ++d0;
        if (d0 >= d1 && d0 >= d2) {
            ++d0;
        }
    }
    n = 10 * n + d0;
    return n;
}
```

As commented, this algorithm will try immensely many randomUnique calls when the size nears MAX_N.

Better would be to take the set of all numbers between 100-999 and then take randomly a subset of the right size.

As this seems some kind of puzzle, home work, just some pointers to a better, often faster algorithm:

```
BitSet uniqueNumbers = new BitSet(1000);
for (int num = 100; num < 1000; ++num) {
    uniqueNumbers.set(num, isUnique(num));
}
... take N elements

boolean isUnique(int num) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why `size = N`? Why not just use `N`? --- Having same-name variables that only differ by case (`N` vs `n`) is a bad idea. If `size` is better than the short `N`, then `number` would be better than the short `n`.

Comment: Since OP's problem occurred while trying to convert "working" code to use streams, perhaps showing a stream version of your solution would be appropriate, e.g. `IntStream.generate(() -> randomUnique(random)).distinct().limit(N).toArray()`

Comment: @Andreas I already upvoted your answer which nicely shows the expressiveness of Stream. As the original solution was a bit of, I first wanted to show what all is possible, like immediately generating a unique number vs. afterwards checking. And twice "random" as in random integers is a tiny bit suspect. For the rest you brought up valid arguments..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating random numbers, to test them and drop invalid ones, you can generate valid numbers in the first place.

Just generate them digit by digit. The first one, at the hundreds position, has to be in the 1…9 range without additional constraints, so we can generate it directly. The second has to be in the 0…9 range, but it must not be equal to the first, so we can generate a digit in the 1…9 range and replace it with zero if it is equal to the first. Likewise, the digit for the last position is generated in the 2…9 range and replaced with zero if equal to the first number or with one if equal to the second. Then, we have a valid number without any need to repeat the process.

As a simple loop, it looks like

```
if(N > 648) throw new IllegalArgumentException("There can't be "+N+" unique numbers");
ThreadLocalRandom r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

Set<Integer> result = new LinkedHashSet<>(N);
while(result.size() < N) {
    int hundreds = r.nextInt(1, 10);
    int tens = r.nextInt(1, 10);
    if(tens == hundreds) tens = 0;
    int ones = r.nextInt(2, 10);
    if(ones == hundreds) ones = 0;
    if(ones == tens) ones = 1;
    result.add(hundreds * 100 + tens * 10 + ones);
}
```

By using a `Set` and testing the size instead of using a counting loop, we ensure to generate `N` unique numbers.

---

Alternatively, we can create a reusable list of all valid numbers first and then, the task changes to “pick N items from a list”, which can be reused in other contexts too.

Generating all valid numbers is simple, iterate over all digits and skip invalid ones, then calculate the number, again, that’s simpler than to iterate over all numbers and testing them, needing an expensive digit extraction.

```
List<Integer> validNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
for(int h = 1; h < 10; h++) {
    for(int t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
        if(t == h) continue;
        for(int o = 0; o < 10; o++) {
            if(o != t && o != h) validNumbers.add(h * 100 + t * 10 + o);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, we can pick `N` unique elements:

```
if(N > validNumbers.size()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

// copying, so validNumbers can be reused
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(validNumbers);

if(N == result.size()) {
    Collections.shuffle(result);
}
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        Collections.swap(result, i, r.nextInt(i, result.size()));
    }
    result.subList(N, result.size()).clear();
}
```

The first branch, when `N == validNumbers.size()`, we just need to shuffle the numbers and have `N` valid random elements. The alternative, when `N` is smaller, basically does the same as `shuffle` does internally, but omits the work for the elements we don’t pick and removes them at the end.

---

We can express the same logic with the Stream API, but it’s not always a win.

The first variant could be

```
List<Integer> result = IntStream.generate(() -> {
        ThreadLocalRandom r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        int h = r.nextInt(1, 10), t = r.nextInt(1, 10), o = r.nextInt(2, 10);
        if(t == h) t = 0;
        if(o == h) o = 0;
        if(o == t) o = 1;
        return h * 100 + t * 10 + o;
    })
    .distinct().limit(N).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You may replace `.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())` with `toArray()` if an `int[]` array result is sufficient.

For the second approach we can use

```
int[] validNumbers = IntStream.range(1, 10)
    .flatMap(h -> IntStream.range(0, 10).filter(t -> t != h)
        .flatMap(t -> IntStream.range(0, 10).filter(o -> o != t && o != h)
            .map(o -> h * 100 + t * 10 + o)))
    .toArray();
```

to get the valid numbers and

```
List<Integer> result = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
    .ints(0, validNumbers.length)
    .distinct().limit(N)
    .mapToObj(ix -> validNumbers[ix])
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to pick `N` distinct elements (which may be more expensive than the `shuffle` approach). Again, you can replace `.mapToObj(ix -> validNumbers[ix]) .collect(Collectors.toList())` with `.map(ix -> validNumbers[ix]) .toArray()` when an `int[]` array result is sufficient.